# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile

I want to remove all activities in the back stack when opening a new activity but it's not working.
This is the code i have for it. Thanks

`Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(intent);`

Comment: what error you are getting and what do you want to achieve. Can you please ask a proper question mentioning these things

Comment: _"I want to remove all activities in the back stack when opening a new activity"_ That's not what `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` does. From the documentation (emphasis mine): _If set, **and the activity being launched is already running in the current task**, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other **activities on top of it will be closed** and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent_. Note how only some activities will be closed, and they will only be closed if the activity you're starting already exists in the back stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set these following flags :

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```